# Show Fraction values in highchart

Tags: php, json, highcharts

In high chart Y axis i want to show some fraction values like 100/50, 100/70
100/90

Is it possible? please help me how to show that values.

```js
$.getJSON('1.php?ID=' + <?php echo $Id; ?>, function(json) {
    $('#container').highcharts({
             chart: {
                 renderTo: 'container',
                 type: 'spline',
     animation: Highcharts.svg,
                 marginRight: 130,
                 marginBottom: 25,
    
             },
             title: {
                 text: 'Lab',
                 x: -20 //center
             },
             subtitle: {
                 text: '',
                 x: -20
             },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'time',
     tickPixelInterval: 007
    },
             yAxis: {
                 title: {
                     text: 'Lab'
                 },
                 plotLines: [{
                     value: 0,
                     width: 1,
                     color: '#808080'
                 }]
             },
             
             legend: {
                 layout: 'vertical',
                 align: 'right',
                 verticalAlign: 'top',
                 x: -10,
                 y: 100,
                 borderWidth: 0
             },
    exporting: {
     enabled: true
    },
            series: [{
                                        name: 'Lab',
                                        data: json.data,
                                        datataLabels: {
                                             enabled: true,
                                             rotation: -90,
                                             color: '#FFFFFF',
                                            align: 'right',
                                            y: 10,
                                                  style: {
                                                       fontSize: '13px',
                                                       fontFamily: 'Verdana, sans-serif',
                                                       textShadow: '0 0 3px black',

                                                        }
                                                  }
                                              }]
         });
     });
```

1.php have just MySQL retrial query 
    $sth = mysql_query("SELECT DateandTime,BP FROM table  WHERE ID='".$Id."'");

Comment: I believe they dynamically assign these values and creates those ranges dynamically so its essentially gonna be floats/ints instead of string. Still if want want to change you'll have to dig into its source files

Comment: Do you mean that labels on yAxis should have these "names", or data should be ranged?

Comment: Data range @SebastianBochan

Comment: i put my values dynamically get from database. i cant able to access that fraction values . only i can access int and float values @ɢʜʘʂʈʀɛɔʘɴ

Comment: How your data looks like ?

Comment: 100/50, 100/70 100/90 just like that @SebastianBochan

Comment: I mean JSON, how looks like

Comment: please check the json code above @SebastianBochan

Comment: I mean JSON (data object), in that form { field:value } not request to database, becase we have no structure of that.

Comment: series: [{
name: 'PlotName',
data: [100/20, 100/40, 100/60, 100/80, 100/90]
}]
@SebastianBochan

Comment: Your JSON is not valid (please check by jslint), I recommend you to use something like [{ name: 'PlotName', data: [{high:100, low:20} }] and then use correct serie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish what I believe that you are indicating that you want by do a few things listed below.

First, you will need to restructure your JSON packet to include labels that Highcharts can use in a series, as follows:

```
var json = {
    data: [ ["100/50",(100/50)], ["100/60",(100/60)], ["100/75",(100/75)], ["100/30",(100/30)] ]
};
```

Then you will need to make a few adjustments to your chart js, so that you override the default tooltip by adding this block inside the highcharts config object (right after the xAxis block is a good place for it):

```
xAxis: {
    //some xAxis overrides here
},
tooltip: {
    pointFormat: ''
},
```

What that does is basically tell highcharts to make the tooltip data point '', so in essence it isn't rendered but the label still shows up on your mouseovers.

That having been done, your yAxis labels will still be decimal values representing the range steps of the fractions, so you will either want to suppress that or handle it otherwise.